# ESX3.5 Performance CPU wait counter

Tags: performance, vmware-esx

After looking at various vms on several ESX hosts I notice that the CPU wait counter is always hovering around the 95-100% mark. Is this normal? I can't seem to find many good resources regarding this counter.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal - There is a [very good article on VMware Communities](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-9279) on interpreting ESXTOP counters that says:

> Q: Why do I always see a high %WAIT
>   for VMX/mks worlds?
>   A: This is normal.
>   That means there are not too much
>   activities on them.